# The instance of entity type 'Product' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate, change-tracking, asp.net-boilerplate

I made a test with code below to update the `Product`:

```
var existing = await _productRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == input.Id);
if (existing == null)
    throw new UserFriendlyException(L("ProductNotExist"));
var updatedEntity = ObjectMapper.Map<Product>(input);
var entity = await _productRepository.UpdateAsync(updatedEntity);
```

But it throws an exception:

> Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - The instance of entity type 'Product' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

This is caused by querying `existing`. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are not using the `existing` entity, don't load it.

Use `AnyAsync` to check if it exists:

```cs
var exists = await _productRepository.GetAll().AnyAsync(c => c.Id == input.Id); // Change
if (!exists)                                                                    // this
    throw new UserFriendlyException(L("ProductNotExist"));

var updatedEntity = ObjectMapper.Map<Product>(input);
var entity = await _productRepository.UpdateAsync(updatedEntity);
```

If you want to map to the `existing` entity:

```
var existing = await _productRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == input.Id);
if (existing == null)
    throw new UserFriendlyException(L("ProductNotExist"));

var updatedEntity = ObjectMapper.Map(input, existing); // Change this
```

Answer (score 7):

`AsNoTracking()` could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `updatedEntity.Id`, if it's zero then use the below code.

```
var updatedEntity = ObjectMapper.Map<Product>(input);
updatedEntity.Id = input.Id; //set Id manually
var entity = await _productRepository.UpdateAsync(updatedEntity);
```

Answer (score -1):

add code for detaching

_dbcontext.Entry(oldEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;

Comment: The EntityState is already detached in this case.