# EntityFramework upades keep sync with data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two classes:

```
[Table("Accomplishments")]
public class Accomplishment : AuditedEntity 
{

    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual int? CriteriaGroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CriteriaGroupId")]
    public CriteriaGroup CriteriaGroupFk { get; set; }

}

 [Table("CriteriaGroups")]
public class CriteriaGroup : CreationAuditedEntity 
{       
    public List<CriteriaGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

I have a ui where I have a save action to create or update the whole accomplishement with the subclasses.

My issue is that:

First time: the user through the ui Selects the CriteriaGroup1 and CriteriaGroup2  --> Saving is ok and criteria group are both created with the accomplmishment

Second time: the user through the ui Selects CriteriaGroup3 and deselect CriteriaGroup1 -->> Then I save and CriteriaGroup3 is well created. But CriteriaGroup1 should be removed from the database and it stills inside.

EntityFramework doesn't remove automatically the entity difference between two savings?

So how can I do it? How can it be managed automatically with EF core?

Thanks,

Comment: `the user through the ui Selects CriteriaGroup3 and deselect CriteriaGroup1 -->> Then I save and CriteriaGroup3 is well created. But CriteriaGroup1 should be removed from the database and it stills inside.` where is that code?

Comment: It's an angular UI. And I get the accomplishment object and update the object. In the normal behaviour it should remove the objects not linked anymore?

Comment: I am asking about your .net (presuming controller) code that links whatever in response to Angular HTTP requests. Angular wouldn't manipulate the db directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are updating a entity, you should include the child entities (foreign key entities) as well you are updating them. Otherwise when you adding them, they keep adding without removing the already existing ones.

```
var accomplishment = dataContext.Accomplishments.Where(a => a.Id = id)
.Include(a => a.CriteriaGroupFk)
.FirstOrDefault();

accomplishment.CriteriaGroupFk = [Your new List]

dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Now entity framework delete previously linked child entities if there are no longer there.

Comment: I tried your solution and I have the error: 'The instance of entity type 'Accomplishment' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'
An idea?

Comment: OK I fixed it thanks to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798566/the-instance-of-entity-type-product-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance

Comment: Now I  see that accomplishmentId in my criteriagroup table is null. That is a good point. However it doesn't remove the row. Is it the normal behaviour? Should I schedule a sql server job to delete the rows with accomplishmentid=null?

Comment: No you shouldn't be doing that at all. EF does that for you.
On your first comment, you shouldn't get that either. I can't guess what might go wrong there without seeing the code. Are you doing  dataContext.accomplishment.Add(accomplishment) before saving? If yes that's what causing the issue.